# NSScrollView vertical align

Tags: swift, macos, alignment, nsscrollview

I want to do scrolling vertical stack (Swift, Cocoa Mac app).
For that purpose I placed NsStackView in NSScrollView.

At first glance everything is okay:

[image: image 1]

but when I move to the top side of window, the stack's content doesn't move and stays at the bottom of NSScrollView, and when I move to the bottom side of window, the stack's content moves with the bottom side of NSScrollView:

[image: image 2]

This is the part of storyboard:

[image: image 3]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild assumption on my end, but wouldn't a table view suit your needs better? Also, some code would be helpful in finding the issue.

Comment: Do you use gravity areas?

Comment: @ZoltanVari there is no code, only elements in IB. And I am think NSTableView has no scroll..

Comment: @Willeke I'm already tried to use all of these options, nothing helped :(

Comment: But I found the some helpful example: https://github.com/mattiasjahnke/NSStackView-Scroll. There is some code in ViewController, which solved the problem